# Extract string using rm_between in mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to extract the value between "Height: " and "cm" in the below string

```
x <- "Height : 13cm Width : 14cm"
```

The result should be `13`

I'm using `rm_between` from the `qdapRegex` package, and it works fine when applying it to a string:

```
> rm_between("Height : 13cm Width : 14cm","Height : ","cm",extract=TRUE)[[1]]
[1] "13"
```

However, when I apply the same function in a mutate function on a dataframe, it doesn't seem to work:

```
# Create test dataframe
ID <- c("1","2","3")
Values <- c("A","B","Height : 13cm Width : 14cm")
dfTest <- data.frame(ID,Values)

# Apply rm_between in mutate
dfTest <- dfTest %>%
  mutate(Height = if_else(str_detect(Values,"Height : "),rm_between(Values,"Height : ","cm",extract=TRUE)[[1]],"None"))
```

Output:

```
> dfTest
  ID                     Values Height
1  1                          A   None
2  2                          B   None
3  3 Height : 13cm Width : 14cm   <NA>
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringr` has functions which can help you with such extractions of text.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dfTest %>% mutate(Values = str_extract(Values, '(?<=Height\\s:\\s)\\d+(?=cm)'))

#  ID Values
#1  1   <NA>
#2  2   <NA>
#3  3     13
```

`(?<=)` and `(?=)` are lookbehind and lookahead regex specifying that extract a number (`\\d+`) which is between `'Height\\s:\\s'` and `'cm'`.

---

To use `qdapRegex::rm_between` you can do :

```
dfTest %>% 
   mutate(Values = unlist(qdapRegex::rm_between(Values, 
                          "Height : ","cm",extract=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `if_else` expression:

```
dfTest %>%
  mutate(Height = rm_between(Values,"Height : ","cm", extract = TRUE))
  ID                     Values Height
1  1                          A     NA
2  2                          B     NA
3  3 Height : 13cm Width : 14cm     13
```

Comment: `dfTest$` inside `rm_between` might not be needed?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(dplyr)
dfTest %>%
    mutate(Height = readr::parse_number(Values))
```

-output

```
#   ID                     Values Height
#1  1                          A     NA
#2  2                          B     NA
#3  3 Height : 13cm Width : 14cm     13
```